# What does 'still more' mean?

Tags: meaning

> These institutions were started by Brougham and Birkbeck in the twenties at a time
>   when, as a writer described it, “there still prevailed in many quarters a strong
>   jealousy of any political discussion by the people, and **still more** of any society
>   which proposed to assemble periodically several hundreds of the labouring
>   classes”. Hence their founders, in their desire to conciliate opposition, banned
>   political or religious discussion or books, and forbade newspapers.

How do the adverbs **still + more** compound to generate its meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Even more**
**yet more**
**greater still**

*Noun:*
There (existential there)

*verb*
prevailed

*adverb*
still

*subject complement*
a strong jealousy

1) of any political discussion by the people

*conjunction:*
and

*adverb*
still more (=even more)

2) of any society which...

---

I like baseball even/still more than I like football.