# How do I deduce when to use "still less" vs. "still more" as conjunctions?

Tags: word-choice

Please don't (ask me to) reword or paraphrase! I need this syntax to learn when to use [***still <sup>more</sup>***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/36834)  and ***still <sub>less</sub>***.

## 1. What's the lexical category (part of speech) of *still <sup>**more**</sup>* and *still <sub>**less**</sub>* here?

### Verb with positive polarity (e.g. like)

My number 1 life goal is H (Happiness). My number 2 life goal is  L (Longevity). To communicate that I like H more than L, is 1 correct? 2 feels wrong to me, but I don't know why?

> 2. I like L, ***still <sup>more</sup>*** H.
> 3. I like L, ***still <sub>less</sub>*** H.

### Verb with negative polarity (e.g. hate)

W (War) irks me more, and is deadlier, than R (Racism). To communicate that I hate W more than R, is 4 or 5 correct? I have no clue how to decide!

> 4. I hate R, ***still <sup>more</sup>***  W.
> 5. I hate R, ***still <sub>less</sub>*** W.

To no avail, I read https://english.stackexchange.com/q/390946,
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/498115,
https://english.stackexchange.com/q/503152.

Comment: IMO these aren't very natural uses of "still less/more". The examples in the question you link are better.

Comment: They are not conjunctions. The adverb "still" is an additive focusing modifier. It modifies the adverbs "less" / "more".

Comment: "I need this syntax"  Why??

Comment: Why are you writing "more" and "less" in superscript / subscript.  There is much about his question that is unclear.

Comment: @JamesK How can I understand how ***still more*** works without this syntax? I am focussing ***still more*** here, not rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Still less** must follow a negative verb (*grammatically* negative, not 'with a negative meaning'). You are saying that what isn't true of one thing is even less true of another.

> I like C, still more H.
>
> I don't like R, still less W.

Answer (score 0):

"more" and "less" are adverbs, and "still" is (as BillJ says) an "additive focusing modifier"  That is it "additive" since it indicates something additional, it widens the sense of "more", rather than restricting it. It is a focusing modifier as it is used to emphasize a particular part of a sentence.

However you **should** rephrase these.  Don't use superscript or subscript and don't use "H" or "L", use the words in full.  Don't use "still more" as this is non-idiomatic.  Don't talk about life goals with weak verbs "like"

> Longevity is important to me, but not as important as happiness.

Comment: Thanks. I fully agree with your last paragraph, but it is redundant to my question. Please peruse the first sentence of my post.

Comment: Thanks, I've downvoted your question as the incorrect typography and the refusal to consider variation makes it less useful.

Comment: Please correct whatever typography is incorrect to you. Downvote is unjust. " the refusal to consider variation"? You appear to be fighting my hypothetical and question. How can I understand how ***still more*** works without this syntax?